# unicode string literals in C++/CLI

Tags: string, unicode, c++-cli, literals, unicode-literals

Lets say I have this fragment of code which returns a unicode CLR string with Cyrillic letters

```
    property String^ EIDErrorDescriptionSr { 
       String^ get() 
       {
        switch(EIDErrorCode) 
        {
         case EID_OK: return "Операција успешно завршена";
...
```

When I read the property in C# code referencing this assembly, I get a bunch of the "?" as if the C++ compiler "flattened" the string to single-byte chars.

I did save the C++ source file as UTF-8 (even Unicode) and I always get this warning from the compiler for every non-ansi character:

> warning C4566: character represented
>   by universal-character-name '\u041E'
>   cannot be represented in the current
>   code page (1252)

Now, is there a compiler switch to force compiler to treat literals as unicode? I can't seem to find one.

Comment: Try a Unicode string literal: `L"..."`.

Comment: d'oh. thanks, it works. I was so hanged on to blaming the compiler, didn't even consider this.

Comment: @Philipp: Post your answer below.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: Done. (Usually I avoid posting answers that consist of single lines and that I haven't tested.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a Unicode string literal: `L"..."`.